# How to send e-mail to customer after order payment was successful?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, order-status, order-email

I need to send the confirmation e-mail to customer only on successful payment. How can I do it?

I need to place that code in the controller that inserts the payment information in database and before redirecting to the success page.

Comment: are you using custom payment method or default payment method?

Comment: Custom payment method. It is all OK but the confirmation e-mail to customer.